# What should I do when my client keeps revealing more requirements?

Tags: software-industry, salary, freelancing, telecommute, contract-extension

I am a freelance developer and a virtual assistant. I assist my clients with technical things like getting something to work in Linux. I work from home and my clients use online instant messaging platform to communicate with me (take Skype as an example).

Recently, I got a client needing assistance with something technical. He has a company and he is the one who hired me, but after he hired me he told me that I have to work with his staff, and not directly with him. He acts as a middle man and I report him the progress daily, his staff are who I help remotely.

Now, after I have completed his job, he revealed another requirement which I did not know of before accepting to work for a certain fee. The other requirement is related but not inclusive **i.e the requirement cannot be satisfied if the first original requirement is met... but my client thought that it would** and he did not tell me about it.

I offered him some suggestions but I did not start working towards his other requirement as I was already spending too much time on his project. I will be happy to help him if he can pay more than what we initially agreed upon. I did not talk to him about this yet and I am worried that he might regret his decision of hiring me, I don't want him to have a bad experience with me.

Should I decline to do the extra work? Charge another fee?

Comment: If you think this one don't answer to your question, please edit your question and add details to make it clear in what your situation is different from that one.

Comment: Hang in there! Give 'em an inch and they'll expect a yard :O :D.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Walfrat, I will check the question and edit if needed

Comment: Your question is a variation on the classic "my clients is demanding extra work after we already agreed on price and scope" which the linked question basically covers. This does seem like a fairly clear duplicate to me.

Comment: @Walfrat The question was relavent but not an answer to my situation, my client is not asking me "small questions" and we do not have a long term-relationship. We only met 4 days ago :)

Comment: The context is different, the answer is still the same : TIme is money.

Comment: I see... but I still think that this question is different enough to not mark as a duplicate

Comment: For every new requirement he 'reveals' to you, you 'reveal' a new quote to him. Your price for the job was based on the specs he gave you, not the overarching dream in his head. This is probably not your fault, so don't make it your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" I don't want him to have a bad experience with me."

So you rather want to be the one with a bad experience with him? He specifically asked you to do something to which you agreed. You did this so your project has finished and he has to pay you. If he wants something more, you can always start a new project with the new specifications. And this is also how I would communicate the situation. Say that you are happy that he thinks that the first project is finished and that he wants to continue working with you and then propose a new project with a new price.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @FooBar, I will propose him to start a new project for the said requirement and pay me for the work done until now. Again, thank you very much for clearing the confusion! :)